# split string into array without deleting delimiter ruby

Tags: regex, ruby

I am new to ruby. I need to split a string into an array according to the regex pattern and preserve delimiter.
For example, I have a string of logs

```
"@2019-01-09 09:01:05,333 ERROR-Log Message
@2019-01-09 09:01:05,333 ERROR-Log Message
@2019-01-09 09:01:05,333 WARNING-Log Message
@2019-01-09 09:01:05,333 WARNING-Log Message"

my regex pattern is /^(@[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3}).*/
```

and I want to get something like this

```
["@2019-01-09 09:01:05,333 ERROR-Log Message", "@2019-01-09 09:01:05,333 ERROR-Log Message", "@2019-01-09 09:01:05,333 WARNING-Log Message", "@2019-01-09 09:01:05,333 WARNING-Log Message"]
```

Comment: Don't you want to just split with a newline?

Comment: Or split with `/(?!\A)(?=^@\d{4}(?:-\d{2}){2} \d{2}(?::\d{2}){2},\d{3})/`?

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works for me now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the following regex with `.split`:

```
/(?!\A)(?=^@\d{4}(?:-\d{2}){2} \d{2}(?::\d{2}){2},\d{3})/
```

It is a combination of two lookaheads:

- `(?!\A)` -  not at the start of the string
- `(?=^@\d{4}(?:-\d{2}){2} \d{2}(?::\d{2}){2},\d{3})` - start of a line position that is followed with `@\d{4}(?:-\d{2}){2} \d{2}(?::\d{2}){2},\d{3}` pattern that matches `@`, then a date-like pattern, then a space, adn then a time-like pattern.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZxYVCv/1).